# Changing User Name breaks ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have the following I use to change the UserName

```
// POST: /Manage/ChangeUserName
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeUserName(ChangeUserNameViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            user.UserName = model.NewUserName;
            var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangeUserNameSuccess });
            }
            AddErrors(result);
            return View(model);
        }
```

It successfully changes the name in the DB.
However once I log out. I can't log back in.

The user is still in the DB. 
And the Login code

```
 var result = await SignInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync(model.Provider, model.Code, isPersistent: model.RememberMe, rememberBrowser: model.RememberBrowser);
```

Just returns `SignInStatus.Failure`

No other errors are occurring.
Any ideas why that is occurring?

Comment: Do you get an error? or is it just not finding the user?  have you ensured that all the names have been updated (ie, perhaps theres another identity table with the email in, etc.)?

Comment: @Johan No errors. correct user gets updated. There is only the `AspNetUsers` table AFAIK that stores the email/username

Comment: Hmm, is the user still confirmed/activated after the change?

Comment: Yes. The user is not Deactivated or Locked Out. The only thing i change is the Username

Comment: Out of interest, does it work if you reset IIS/completely kill the app and start it again?  My thinking is, it might not have updated in the context that is still alive. (unrelated question, but the answer might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331293/asp-net-identity-2-external-sign-in-not-saving-userlogin-and-not-finding-user-af)