# Blazor change Primary Key for Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, asp.net-identity

I need to change my primary key for my ASP.NET Identity users. I have a similar issue like here [Changing User Name breaks ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882740/changing-user-name-breaks-asp-net-identity) **BUT** I am using blazor.

I found according documentation from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity BUT it is only for Webforms and MVC.

Any idea how I can change the primary auth key from Username to Email?

Comment: Unclear. UserName is not the primary key, just a candidate key you can search on. But so is Email. Ther should be no need to change anything.

Comment: So I thought, but if I change the Username after a user is registered it breaks login. I read in a Github Issue that it has somthing to to with the way Identity identitifes userns based on the username. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/7995

Comment: Was the Username initially the same s the email?  You do have to look at the login logic, out of the box it won't work.